# Why is quicksand named so if you get sucked in so slowly?

Tags: meaning

Why is quicksand called "quick" if it sucks in so slowly?

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the *quick* in the word *quicksand* has the old meaning of *[quick](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick)*:

> *Archaic*
>   **a.** endowed with life.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=quicksand&searchmode=none):

> c.1400, from M.E. *quyk* "living" (see ***[quick](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=quick&searchmode=none)***) + *sond* "sand."

So *quicksand* doesn't mean *fast sand*, but *living sand*.

Comment: Just like the Biblical prhase "the quick and the dead" means "the living and the dead", not "those fast enough to get out of the way of oncoming cars and those who weren't". :-)

Comment: cf. mercury = quick silver